# Was this done right (domain)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, proof-verification

I have a function $\frac{1}{\tan(x)+1}$ 
So I know $\tan(x)+1$ can not be undefined or zero

We know $\tan(x)$ can not equal $n(\pi)+(\pi/2)$

Therefore tan $(x)+1$ can not equal $n(\pi)+(\pi/2)$

Bring to other side and simplify: $\tan(x)$ can not equal $n(\pi)-(\pi/2)$

$\tan(x)+1$ can not equal zero

$\tan(x)+1$ can not equal $-1$

Therefore $\tan(x)$ can not equal $n(\pi)-(\pi/2)$ and $-1$

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. You can learn how to write mathematical formulas [here.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: What do you **mean** by "bring to the other side"?  The "other side" of what?

Comment: You're confusing arguments of $\tan\$ and its values.

Comment: tan (x) can not equal zero

Comment: Than what would be the correct way of doing it?

Comment: I don't understand anything starting from the second line. Just solve $\tan(x)+1=0$ for $x$ in the (maximal) domain where $\tan$ is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try being more precise. Consider the function
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\tan(x)+1}
$$
which we want to determine the domain of:

1. $\tan(x)$ should be defined
2. $\tan(x)+1$ should not be $0$.

We know that $\tan(x)$ is defined for $x\ne\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi$ ($n$ integer), so we have settled condition 1.

Suppose $\tan(x)+1=0$; then $\tan(x)=-1$ and so $x=-\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi$ ($n$ integer). This settles condition 2: we must have $x\ne-\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi$ ($n$ integer).

---

Beware of the common error of saying that “$\tan(x)$ cannot equal $n\pi+\pi/2$”. Actually it *can*, because the tangent function hits every real value (infinitely many times). It is $x$ that cannot equal $n\pi+\pi/2$.

Also from $\tan(x)+1\ne0$ you get $\tan(x)\ne-1$, not $\tan(x)+1\ne-1$.